# "Select all" and search field in a table

Tags: tables, multi-selection, search-results

I'm looking for a solution that will allow to send specific items by clicking "Send". The selection of these items should be done while allowing:

1. Adding specific value by search (narrows results on the fly).
2. Selecting all / none.
3. Selecting specific row(s).

I thought of using something like the one seen below but not sure about the conflicts it may create. For example:

- Should typing a specific value and getting, for example, 3 items and then click "Select all" affect only the presented values or all of them?
- When selecting a value, then use the search field to search other items, will the checkbox still be be checked for the other items?

Is there any better solution for this case? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**"Select all" should apply to the filtered item list**.

If the user has searched for something, they may want the functionality of selecting all search results.  The user will expect the "select all" functionality to apply to the current items they are looking at.  I don't think this will cause any confusion (doing the opposite would be confusing).

**Searching should remove any selection**.

This really follows from the above--selection is a feature that applies to the currently visible list of items.  Having non-visible items that are selected would be counterintuitive.  So if the visible list is changed, this should reset the selection.

This perhaps does raise a problem, though: *What if the user wants to search for several terms and add results from each to the selected list?*

If that is your use case, then the current design is inadequate, as there is no way to do it clearly.  You should move to a "list builder" design, with a separate box where the user can add selected items.  [This recent answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/85439/31143) shows an example.